# its possible consume a spring boot api rest from JSF?

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot, jsf

I try execute a ajax query from the xhtml file, and its trows error :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

This is my ajax query:

```
        <h:form>
          <script type="text/javascript">


    llamadaNombre();
    function llamadaNombre(){

       var list2=null;
             $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "localhost:8080/users",
            dataType: "json",
           data: {val: list2},
            success : function(result) {
                $('#tablebody').html("");
                  $.each(result,function(key, val) {
                       editar="<h:commandLink action='/paginas/crud/editarCliente?dni="+val.dni+"' class='btn btn-success'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span> editar </h:commandLink>" ;
                       eliminar="<h:commandLink action='/paginas/crud//eliminarCliente?id="+val.dni+"' class='btn btn-success'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> eliminar </h:commandLink>";
            var htmlrow ="<tr>"+"<td>" + val.id + "</td>"+"<td>" + val.nombre + "</td>"+"<td>" + val.apellidos + "</td>"+"<td>" + val.dni + "</td>"+"<td>" + val.correo + "</td>"+"<td>" + val.telefono + "</td>"+"<td>" + val.direccion + "</td>"+"<td>" + val.cp + "</td>"+"<td>" + val.edad + "</td>"+"<td>" + editar + "</td>"+"<td>" + eliminar + "</td>"+"</tr>";         
             $('#tablebody').append(htmlrow);
        })

            }
        })   

   }

</script>
               </h:form>
```

the format of data in the api rest is json

There are any way for connect api in springBoot and JSF application ? its throw the error:

```
 jquery.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at `'htttp://localhost:8080/users?val=' from origin 'http://localhost:9090' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`
```

i Try change the port in diferents enviorments but its keep returning that error and if configure in the same port trows error that this ports its listening

this is my API controlller:(solved)

```
   @Service
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    public class UsuariosController {


    public List<Clientes> getAll(){

        return clientesFacade.getAllClientes();

    }
```

Comment: How is this jsf related? Jsf runs server-side, javascript client-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the headers param to your request as a bellow script :

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "localhost:8090/users",
    data: {val: list2},
    headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Authorization": .......,
    },
    success: function (data, text) {
         console.log(data);
    },
........
```

in your java controller, you should authorize to access from localhost in your case, you can just add the annotation : `@crossorigin(origins = "localhost" )` to your service.

Comment: i have to activate a aplication of browser for cross autorization